# Online landscape design

Tags: landscaping

I have some guys coming in two weeks to pull the shrubs in the flowerbed in front of our house and replace them with others.  The problem is that I have no idea what I should put in.  Is there an online application (free) where I can mock up ideas to see what they would look like?  Preferably one that allows head-on views more than from-above views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.the-landscape-design-site.com/blog/2008/01/free-landscaping-software-list-of-free-software/) is the most comprehensive review that i've found. but you'll probably be disappointed, because the free online one's are very lame. maybe if you'll use your own image samples of the items, you could use the showoff.com tool, but i didn't liked it.

Comment: It wasn't what I needed, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

The best program for this is Google Sketchup. Why? Because the purpose of it is to easily let you draw in 3D, meaning a perspective view, rather than the view from above.

There is a free version. There is also a professional version which I use, but most homeowners do not need that.
♠
Depending on your ability, it can be very easy or slightly challenging. However, I would give it a try. It's a lot of fun.

Since you are concentrating on a bed in front of your house, or a foundation planting, you will want to draw in your house. This does not have to be exact. However, I would put in the length of the house and correctly locate the windows and doors at the least.

After you select plants, which are called components, you can adjust their size.

I hope this is helpful. Here is the link. [Sketchup](http://sketchup.google.com/)